# How to I mitigate AppendBlock BlobModifiedWhileReading Errors?

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have an Azure Function app consuming messages from an Event Hub and appending the data to block blobs.

We are observing a large volume of BlobModifiedWhileReading errors, which I am told by Microsoft are down to a conflict in read/write modes:

- AppendBlock calls require the blob to be in write-optimized mode
- Calls like GetBlobProperties and ListBlobs, require it to be in
  read-optimized mode

The conflict occurs when the get/put operations are made simultaneously on the same blob - at scale in my case.

The code I am using checks if the blob exists on each request, creates it if required and then appends the blob.

```
if (!await appendBlobClient.ExistsAsync()) {
    await appendBlobClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
}
using var ms = new MemoryStream(blockContent);
await appendBlobClient.AppendBlockAsync(ms);
```

I'm looking for some advice on a pattern to mitigate these errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify the exact error you’re receiving? Is “BlobModifiedWhileReading” a string returned in an error response from storage? Is it a client exception message? I’ve never heard of this error message 
Additionally, it’s not clear how you’re encountering this issue, because you’re giving a code sample of write code, but the exception indicates this was a read operation.

Comment: BlobModifiedWhileReading is the status text shown against the transaction in storage diagnostics with a 409 conflict. I’m currently testing an alternative pattern and will response when I have adequate results.